# Error using "apply" function in Clojure: "Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long"

Tags: exception, clojure, higher-order-functions, first-class-functions

Working on the following example in "Clojure in Action" (p. 63):

```
(defn basic-item-total [price quantity] 
    (* price quantity))

(defn with-line-item-conditions [f price quantity] 
    {:pre [(> price 0) (> quantity 0)]
     :post [(> % 1)]} 
    (apply f price quantity))
```

Evaluating on the REPL:

```
(with-line-item-conditions basic-item-total 20 1)
```

Results in the following exception being thrown:

```
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

It appears the exception is being thrown after the apply procedure is evaluated.

Comment: `apply` is a function, not a macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last argument to `apply` is supposed to be a [*sequence* of arguments](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply). In your case, the usage might look more like this:

```
(defn with-line-item-conditions [f price quantity] 
    {:pre [(> price 0) (> quantity 0)]
     :post [(> % 1)]} 
    (apply f [price quantity]))
```

`apply` is useful when you're working with a list of arguments. In your case, you can simply call the function:

```
(defn with-line-item-conditions [f price quantity] 
    {:pre [(> price 0) (> quantity 0)]
     :post [(> % 1)]} 
    (f price quantity))
```

Comment: Thanks - I see now that in the case of the apply macro, the sequence should be a vector. This was not clear after reading the description after evaluating (doc apply): "Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening arguments to args."

Comment: Yeah, some of the doc strings can be pretty opaque. [The cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) is a great place for example usages.